# Deny user from altering own role

Tags: postgresql

How can I allow a Postgres user to be able to create new roles, but not create a database? The problem I currently have is, if I grant `CREATEROLE` and `NOCREATEDB` to the user, that user is able to alter their own role and set themselves to `CREATEDB`.

This feels like a security loophole, or am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to perform the `CREATE ROLE` statement. `SECURITY DEFINER` ensures that the function will execute with `postgres` (the owners) role privileges even when called from an unprivileged user. Make sure to revoke access from public. Then grant execute rights to the user who is supposed to create new roles:

```
--As user postgres:

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.create_new_user(rolename varchar, pass varchar)
    RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    COST 100
    SECURITY DEFINER
AS $BODY$
BEGIN

EXECUTE 'CREATE ROLE ' 
        || quote_ident(rolename)  
        ||' LOGIN NOSUPERUSER INHERIT 
            CONNECTION LIMIT 3 
            NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE 
            ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '
        || quote_literal(pass);
return true;
END;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.create_new_user(varchar,varchar) 
    OWNER TO postgres;
REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.create_new_user(varchar,varchar) FROM public;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION public.create_new_user(varchar,varchar) TO test_user;

--As user test_user:
SELECT public.create_new_user('username','password');
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Interesting - `'plpgsql'` being quoted is output of psql \df

Comment: From 8.0 to 9.3 it was documented as "*For backward compatibility, the name can be enclosed by single quotes*", since 9.4 [it's](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) "*Enclosing the name in single quotes is deprecated and requires matching case*"

Comment: Sorry I messed it up: Quotes appear in PgAdmins 'CREATE Script' tab. In psql \sf it does not have them.